# how to create custom operators in airflow and use them in airflow template which is running through cloud composer(in google cloud platform)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I need to create a custom airflow operator which I should be able to use in airflow template(Written in python) which is running in cloud composer...

If I create custom airflow operator how can I use it in a template which is running on the cloud(how to make it available for everyone so that they can use that operator)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use Airflow Plugins. https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html

> Airflow has a simple plugin manager built-in that can integrate external features to its core by simply dropping files in your $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins folder.
>   The python modules in the plugins folder get imported, and hooks, operators, sensors, macros, executors and web views get integrated to Airflow’s main collections and become available for use.

Take a look at examples here: https://github.com/airflow-plugins